# Receiving "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." when making multiple API calls

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm working on refactoring an Express project where I need to make multiple API calls.  I currently have 9 separate functions to make each individual API call, and then set it to res.locals after each API call is made.

I've created an array that has all the API URLs I need to hit, and then I have a function that iterates through the array to make all the fetch calls.  However, I'm running into issues setting the headers so the JSON data pulls through, as I receive the below message:

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Depending on how I set my controller, I can either get the controller header and the first API response to render on my page, or I just get the controller header to render.  I haven't been able to find a solution to this given my circumstances, and was wondering if anyone had a suggestion to correct this.  I've pasted what I think should be enough code to troubleshoot, but if there's anything else I can provide please let me know.

API-Helper file (where API calls are made):

```
function getData(req, res, next) {
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
        fetch(links[i])
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(fetchRes => {
            res.locals.i = fetchRes
            next()
        })        
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({err})
        })
    }
}
```

Below is the controller that gets the data from the first API call and the header:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {  
cryptoController.sendApiData = (req, res) => {          
    res.json({
        message: 'data returned for crypto',            
        i: res.locals.i
    })  
    }
}
```

And below is the controller when it just returns the header:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {  
cryptoController.sendApiData = (req, res) => {          
    res.json({
        message: 'data returned for crypto',            
        i: res.locals[i]
    })  
    }
}
```

Updating to display more code:

Full controller:

```
// import model
const Crypto = require('../models/Crypto')

// initiate controller object
const cryptoController = {}

// find latest cap coin entry
cryptoController.latest = (req, res, next) => {
    Crypto.findRecent()
    .then(crypto => {
        res.json({
            message: 'retrieved entry',
            data: { crypto }
        })
    }).catch(next)
}

// send api data
// for (let i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {  
cryptoController.sendApiData = (req, res) => { 
    console.log(res.locals)         
    res.json({
        message: 'data returned for crypto',            
        i: res.locals.i
    })  
    // }
}

// create new entry
cryptoController.create = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body, ' req.body from cryptoController#create')
    Crypto.create({
        // time made
        time_made: Date.now(),
        // crypto data
        usd: req.body.usd,
        us_high: req.body.us_high,
        us_low: req.body.us_low,
        eur: req.body.eur,
        eur_high: req.body.eur_high,
        eur_low: req.body.eur_low,
        trades: req.body.trades,
        one_hour: req.body.one_hour,
        one_day: req.body.one_day,
        seven_days: req.body.Seven_days,
        crypto_id: req.body.crypto_id
    })
}


module.exports = cryptoController
```

Route file:

```
// import dependencies
const express = require('express')
const cryptoController = require('../controllers/crypto-controller')
const cryptoHelpers = require('../services/crypto-helpers')

// set router variable
const cryptoRouter = express.Router()

// set routes to fetch and store API data
cryptoRouter.post('/crypto', cryptoHelpers.getData, cryptoController.create)
cryptoRouter.get('/crypto', cryptoHelpers.getData, cryptoController.sendApiData)

module.exports = cryptoRouter;
```

Server file where routes are brought in:

```
const cryptoRouter = require('./routes/crypto-routes')
app.use('/', cryptoRouter)
```

The model file isn't being hit since nothing is being inserted into the DB at this point.

Comment: You will have to show more context for this controller code (the whole request handler and any code that is executed in that request handler) because as you show it here, it makes no sense.  You are in a `for` loop assigning a custom function to `cryptoController.sendApiData`, but not executing anything.  Plus it does no good to assign 10 different functions to the same variable.  Only the last one will actually be assigned.  Plus, you don't show any code that actually executes `cryptoController.sendApiData()` either.

Comment: The general cause of the error you see is code that sends more than one response for a given request.  You can only send one response.  For example, you can only call `res.json()` once for a given request.  The first time it is called, the data is converted to JSON, sent to the client and the http connection is closed.  No more data can be sent.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, I wouldn't even be able to do this with an async function?

Comment: An async function wouldn't have anything to do with it.  You really need to show us more code and describe what you're trying to do for us to help you more specifically.

Comment: Gotcha.  I just updated my original post to show the route and full controller files, as well as how the route is being initiated in the server.js file.  To clarify:  I currently have 9 API calls that are getting their own function (9 total functions).  I'm trying to refactor so all the API calls can be made in one function to reduce the amount of code written.

Thanks very much for the responses, and let me know if there's any other information/clarification I can send.

Comment: Ok, I post solutions to some of the problems.  I was unsuire exactly what result you're trying to get back from `sendApiData()` so I made a guess, but you can hopefully see how things work and fine tune that if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, one problem is here:

```
function getData(req, res, next) {
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
        fetch(links[i])
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(fetchRes => {
            res.locals.i = fetchRes
            next()
        })        
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({err})
        })
    }
}
```

You are calling `next()` inside a loop.  You can only call `next()` once when you're done with all the operations.  Since it looks like these server-side `fetch()` calls can be done in parallel, you can use `Promise.all()` to see when they are all done.

Then, you also have a problem with putting the data into `res.locals`.  You're just assigning the same `res.locals.i` variable over in a loop which isn't really doing anything particularly useful.

I think you will have to use an array for the data and then change the code that uses `res.locals` later on in the routing chain to access the array.

```
function getData(req, res, next) {
    let promises = links.map(function(link) {
        return fetch(link).then(res => res.json())
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        res.locals.data = results;    // res.locals.data is an array of link json
        next();
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({err});
    });
}
```

Then, in your `.get()` route handler, I don't know exactly why type of result you're trying to achieve, but to return an array of results, you can do something like this:

```
cryptoController.sendApiData = (req, res) => { 
    console.log(res.locals.data)         
    res.json({
        message: 'data returned for crypto',            
        data: res.locals.data
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This did the trick!  Thanks so much for your help with this, I was really confused about Promises for a while but this explanation just kinda made it click.